# Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Console\Command' not found

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5.7, cron-task

I've been trying to run a cron task in my server using Laravel. The problem is that I'm getting this error every time.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Console\Command' not found
```

I've been trying running the `composer install` and `composer dump-autoload,` but nothing changes. I keep getting this error.

I have checked my vendor folder in `Illuminate/Console/Command.php` and everything is in the right place.

How can I solve it or what could be causing it?

Comment: What does your cronjob look like?

Comment: It looks like this `/usr/bin/php /path-to-project/app/Console/Commands/CountProfit.php`

Comment: But it's getting the file, the problem is when it runs it and shows this error

Comment: Laravel has a scheduler that can run your commands, have you tried it? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands

Comment: Yes, but I have to call the PHP script because I can't access to the crontab and the server lets me use scheduled tasks and it's easier, just that I'm getting this problem

Comment: Have you restarted server after install?

Comment: No, I had never thought about it. Could it change something?

Comment: In my case, I configured wrong path: insted of `artisan` I pointed the path to the command itself.